# No implemantation in prolog MAZE

Tags: prolog, maze

[image]

Maze from a to e.

When I run `get(a,e[a]).`

[image: 2]

Comment: Following the guidelines of StackOverflow, log(result/error) is provided in text format, not images. Can you refer to the guide below and correct it?
[how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  /  [do-not-upload-images-of-code-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: According to the error message, ```get/3``` is a predicate predefined in ```library(pce)```. Thus, you must rename it... Try ```myget/3```.

Comment: @slago That's the answer though that error message is really confusing. [pce_principal.get/4](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/xpce/prolog/boot/pce_principal.pl?show=src#get/3)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer I totally agree with you!

Comment: you probably meant *Λαβύρινθος!* :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the previous comment, the problem is that `get/3` is a predicate predefined in `library(pce)`. Fixing your code is simple:

```
door(a,b).
door(b,c).
door(c,d).
door(d,e).

myget(X,X,A,P) :-
    reverse(A,P),
    !.
myget(X,Y,A,P) :-
   once(door(X,Z);door(Z,X)),
   not(member(Z,A)),
   format('I am in room ~w.~n', Z),
   myget(Z,Y,[Z|A],P).
```

Query:

```
?- myget(a,e,[a],P).
I am in room b.
I am in room c.
I am in room d.
I am in room e.
P = [a, b, c, d, e].
```